# Backgrounds in Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, wallpaper

I have a question. How fast can Windows 10 change desktop backgrounds thru a c++ script? Is there a cap? I have tried manually switching backgrounds. I do not know how to write a C++ script to do that, though.

Comment: what is a `C++ script`?

Comment: `c++` does not really have scripts. It's not an interpreted language.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a noob at coding languages. I meant maybe C++ code? Or maybe a BAT script

Comment: Yes, you can say C++ code or C++ program. C++ and BAT scripts are very very different things.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a question

I see two questions

> How fast can Windows 10 change desktop backgrounds thru a c++ script?

Very fast. Insanely fast. In the order of milliseconds, maybe less, and most of that time would probably be spend in loading the image and only a fraction to actually apply it to the background.

> Is there a cap?

No, not that I am aware of.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know of a C++ script that can switch backgrounds?

Comment: There is `c++` code in this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331682/change-wallpaper-programmatically-using-c-and-windows-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331682/change-wallpaper-programmatically-using-c-and-windows-api)

Comment: Thank you very much!